# Closed mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been trying to prove the following:
Assume that $X$,$Y$ are two normed spaces. Let $T$ be a closed mapping
$T: X \to Y$ show that the image $A$ of a compact subset $C$ in $X$ is closed.

Show that the inverse image $B$ of a compact subset $K$ of $Y$ is closed in $X$.

I think that I have succeeded with the first part of the problem by usigneret that the graph of $T$ on $C$ is closed and thus $A$ must also be closed.

The second part is harder: then I want to assume that $T$ is either invertible or bounded, but I can't show that it is.

Comment: compact subsets in a Hausdorff space are closed, so everything follows by this observation.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem: If $C$ is compact in $X$ then is closed and thus $T(C)$ is closed in $Y$.

For the second problem:Because $T$ is closed map,we have that $T^{-1}$ is continuous and continuous image of a compact set is compact and hence $T^{-1}(K)$ is compact and thus closed in $X$.

Comment: @user108875 ,check my proof please.thank you